# Sections of a divisor on elliptic curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, computer-algebra, line-bundles, elliptic-curves

I'm interested in producing explicit bases for the sections of a line bundle on an embedded genus 1 curve.  Let me restrict to the first case that I don't know how to do, so that I can be as concrete as possible.   Take a smooth genus 1 curve E defined over QQ by an explicit cubic equation C<sub>0</sub> in QQ[x,y,z].  Let D be a divisor of degree 6 on E, and I_D be defined by four cubic equations (C<sub>0</sub>,C<sub>1</sub>,C<sub>2</sub>,C<sub>3</sub>).  Note that D does not lie on any conic.  Riemann-Roch says that h^0(E,O<sub>E</sub>(D))=6, and I'd like to find an explicit basis of rational functions for this vector space.  How do I find such a basis?

Note that if D sat on a conic defined by Q, then finding a basis is relatively easy:  we could simply choose the functions x^2/Q, xy/Q, ..., z^2/Q as our rational functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know how to answer this now.  The main point is that O<sub>E</sub>(D) is the dual of I<sub>D</sub>.  Namely: O<sub>E</sub>(D)=sheafHom(I<sub>D</sub>,  O<sub>E</sub>).  Thus, H^0(E,O<sub>E</sub>(D))=Hom(I<sub>D</sub>,  O<sub>E</sub>).

This can be computed explicitly in any computer algebra package.  Or you can see how to compute it as follows.  Take a free presentation of I<sub>D</sub> as an O<sub>E</sub>-module.  In the case I asked about, this yields:

O<sub>E</sub><sup>3</sup>(-4)-->O<sub>E</sub><sup>3</sup>(-3)-->I<sub>D</sub>.

Label the first map F.  Then Hom(I<sub>D</sub>,  O<sub>E</sub>) is just the kernel of the map of free modules:

Hom(O<sub>E</sub><sup>3</sup>(-3),  O<sub>E</sub>)--> Hom(O<sub>E</sub><sup>3</sup>(-4),  O<sub>E</sub>)

induced by composition with F.  Thus, computing a free presentation of the ideal sheaf I<sub>D</sub> yields a presentation of H^0(E,O<sub>E</sub>(D)) as the kernel of a map of free modules.

Answer (score 2):

For an explicit example I believe Magma can do this: check out the [this](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/htmlhelp/text1289.htm#13097) part of the documentation.

Comment: This is helpful, and very cool that Magma can do it.  But I am also looking for more insight into how to do this in general.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to play with rational functions of the form x<sup>n</sup>/Q<sub>1</sub>Q<sub>2</sub>, perhaps they will form a big part of a basis?

Answer (score 0):

Let H be a hyperplane section of your cubic and let x be one of the three non trivial halves
of D-2H in Pic^0(X). If you embed E in the complete linear system |H+x|,  then D now sits an a conic; all you needed is a cubic field extension.